# How to count occurrences of substring in string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a website in JavaScript, and I am trying to count how many times a substring occurs in a string.

Example:

```
countOccurences('the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.', 'the')
//Output: 2

countOccurences('the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.', 'the quick')
//Output: 1
```

Also keep in mind that I need the substring to support spaces, like in the second example.

Comment: `str.indexOf(searchElement, fromIndex)` returns an index of a match. if no match is found it returns `-1`. how about you try a loop or recursion that increases a counter until no match is found?

Comment: function countOccurences(str, seperator) { return str.split(seperator).length - 1 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function countOccurences(str, find) {
  return [...str.matchAll(find)].length
}


console.log(countOccurences(
  'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.', 
  'the'))

console.log(countOccurences(
  'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.', 
  'the quick'))
```